# Voice command to Nao Webots simulator

Tags: voice-recognition, nao-robot, webots, naos-project

Am trying to do an Android app to control nao robot using a webots simulator
and am trying to send voice command to choreograph by my pc microphone so any ideas how to do that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual robots do not run the actual speech recognition because of licensing issues. Therefore even though you can simulate audio input on virtual robots, they cannot recognize the speech.

In theory you can replace `ALSpeechRecognition` by your own service and get the `ALDialog` APIs work with it. You could try with [Vosk](https://alphacephei.com/vosk/install) or [Mozilla DeepSpeech](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/r0.9/?badge=latest), but it is quite some work!